# How to enable azure defender on storage accounts using Pulumi?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, pulumi, azure-defender

I am trying my hand at IaC using Pulumi. I am able to create storage accounts but not enable Azure defender to them. How do I add Azure Defender to identify security threats on my storage accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`security.AdvancedThreatProtection`](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/security/advancedthreatprotection/) resource, for example:

```
const advancedThreatProtection = new azure_native.security.AdvancedThreatProtection("advancedThreatProtection", {
    isEnabled: true,
    resourceId: storageAccount.id,
    settingName: "current",
});
```

Also, see a [full runnable example](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/blob/8711a46ce22db86ac07e30f57cf10c5d0f88fd2d/examples/appservice/index.ts#L22).